# python 2: Slicing pandas dataframe using datetime index skips one day from the wanted date

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have below df with "start_datetime" as index. "start_datetime" is of type class'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp' :

```
                                       col1                        col2 
start_datetime

2017-12-27 01:50:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2017-12-27 01:55:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2017-12-27 02:15:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2017-12-27 02:20:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2017-12-27 02:25:00                  0.000000                       0.0
...                                       ...                       ...
2018-01-15 21:30:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2018-01-15 21:35:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2018-01-15 21:40:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2018-01-15 21:45:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2018-01-15 21:50:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2018-01-15 21:55:00                  0.000000                       0.0
2018-01-15 22:00:00                  0.000000                       0.0
```

I want to slice using the datetime index:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01-00-00') # class'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'

df = df[start: ]
```

Below is what I got:

```
                                                  col1                 col2  
start_datetime
2018-01-02 00:00:00                                0.0                  0.0
2018-01-02 00:05:00                                0.0                  0.0
2018-01-02 00:10:00                                0.0                  0.0
2018-01-02 00:15:00                                0.0                  0.0
2018-01-02 00:20:00                                0.0                  0.0
```

Questions:

1. Why did it slice at "2018-01-02 00:00:00" instead of "2018-01-01 00:00:00" ?
2. How can I slice to include "2018-01-01 00:00:00" ?

I have tried:

```
df = df[start: ]
df = df.loc[(df.index >= start)]
```

I also reset the index and tried `df = df.loc[(df.start_datetime >= start)]` and even hard coded `df = df["2018-01-01 00:00:00": ]`

But none sliced at "2018-01-01 00:00:00"

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `df.loc[start:]`?

Comment: Yes, I did. But, I found the problem. See my reply to @jezrael below.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion problem is `2018-01-01` does not exist. You can check it:

```
print (df['2018-01-01'])

#return unique days by floor 
idx = df.index.floor('d').unique()
#print (idx)

#get datetimes between
print (idx[(idx >= '2017-12-30') & (idx <= '2018-01-02')])
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael! your idx = df.index.floor('d').unique() identified the missing date.
It's funny because when start = '2017-12-31-00-00', it returns starting at '2018-01-01-00-00', so I thought '2018-01-01-00-00' is there. After I ran your idx = df.index.floor('d').unique(), it shows that '2018-01-01-00-00' is missing...weird....

Comment: @wi3o So problem in data? Not sure if understand, starting by `2017-12-31-00-00` return missing date?

Comment: so, the problem is with different part of my codes. I am calling a function from statsmodels, which has an algorithm that silently eliminate one whole day worth of data. I forgot to anticipate for that. But, what I found weird is when I tried to slice df = df['2017-12-31-00-00': ], it returns the sliced df starting at "2018-01-01-00-00". When I tried to slice df = df['2018-01-01-00-00': ], it returns the sliced df starting at "2018-01-02-00-00". When I tried df = df['2018-01-02-00-00': ], it returns starting at "2018-01-03-00-00". Because of this, I thought I have a complete data.

Comment: When I used your code `idx = df.index.floor('d').unique()` it actually shows that I am missing some dates:
DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-26', '2017-12-27', '2017-12-28', '2017-12-29',
               '2017-12-30', '2017-12-31', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03',
               '2018-01-04', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07',
               '2018-01-09', '2018-01-10', '2018-01-11', '2018-01-12',
               '2018-01-13', '2018-01-14', '2018-01-16', '2018-01-17',
               '2018-01-18', '2018-01-19', '2018-01-20', '2018-01-21'])